# Optimal Template Parameter Type of a "Change Max" function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a generic function that takes a reference x and a value y, and if y is greater than x assigns x to y.  (performance critical)

Here is what I have:

```
template<class X, class Y>
inline void chmax(X& x, const Y& y) { if (y > x) x = y; }
```

Is this the best way?

I am concerned about the parameter type "const Y&", what would be the difference if I made it just "Y"?  Will one of the two different ways mess with the optimizer?  What about if Y is a POD type?  Will this force it to call addressof, pass a pointer to the int, and then dereference the pointer?

(I am interested in both a generic C++ answer as well as a C++11 specific one if the two are different.)

Comment: Like they say, profile, then optimize. But if you're worried about it, why not specialize your template for POD types?

Comment: How do you specialize a template for POD types?

Comment: Sorry, it's a function template, so you'd need to overload it in this case. It'd be somewhat messy - with things like inline void chmax(int& x, int y) { ... } and so on for each POD type you wanted to use. Thus the suggestion to profile first and only apply this optimization later if completely necessary.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using two template parameters? How often do you expect operator= to be available when you're using different types? Seems slightly odd to me...

Comment: @Yuushi: I guess it is possible to define both `operator<(X,Y)` and `X::operator=(Y)` across different types X,Y - this is done in numerous places in the standard library for example.  In the event that this has been done the above will use them.  In the event incompatible types are used it will fail at compile time.  If I had of forced them to be the same type it may cause an unnecessary converting constructor or user-defined conversion operator call, before the comparison and assignment.  Is there any negative consequence of using different types other than the "oddness"?

Comment: @Yuushi: I think there is a way to specialize a template for POD types other than defining a new specialization for each possible POD type.  Perhaps using `std::is_pod` somehow.

Comment: I believe it's possible to specialize for POD types, but that's probably not what you want here. Presumably, your intent is to pass POD by value, and non-POD by reference (or something similar) -- but what you care about is *size*, not POD-ness. A struct with dozens of ints may be POD, but still enough for passing by value to be slow. Conversely, a type with one int and a constructor non-POD, but small enough to pass by value perfectly well.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I guess you are right, size is one variable.  For non-POD types we also have to consider how expensive the copy constructor is.  The copy constructor of your one int type may take a long time to execute.

Comment: @Andrew : Have you looked at [Boost.CallTraits](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/call_traits.htm)? It sounds like what you're after.